# What is topology of $[-\infty,\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My analysis book is considering a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow [-\infty,\infty]$, where $X$ is a measurable space. Thus, I deduced that $[-\infty,\infty]$ is treated as a topological space.

What is the topology of $[-\infty,\infty]$ ?

Thank you

Comment: On $(-\infty,+\infty)$, you have the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$, neighbourhoods of $+\infty$ are sets containing some $(c,+\infty]$, similar for $-\infty$. Or, consider the map $f \colon [-\infty,+\infty] \to [-1,1];\; f(x) = \frac{x}{1+\lvert x\rvert}$ (with the obvious interpretation for $x = \pm\infty$), and say that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer OK. Thank you.

Comment: But to consider measurable $f : [-\infty,\infty]$ one need not first consider a topology.  One can define $f$ is measurable iff $\{x : f(x) < c\}$ is measurable for all $c \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @GEdgar My aim was to prove the equivalent defintion that you stated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the number of unanswered question, there are a few (equivalent) ways we can think of this topology:

- The order topology (with the natural order), which is induced by the subbase of rays $[-\infty,a)$ and $(a,+\infty]$ where $a\in\Bbb R$.
- The topology making the bijection $f:[-\infty,+\infty]\to[-1,1],$ given by $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ for $x\in\Bbb R$ and $f(\pm\infty)=\pm 1$, a homeomorphism.
- The two-point compactification of $\Bbb R.$